# No option for creating new repo in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio (community, free) for Mac, version 17.3. I'm trying to create a new repo in GitHub for pushing my code, but that option, [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-create-repository?view=vs-2022), simply doesn't exist.

[image]

The only options I have are "Clone Repository", and then "Push", "Pull", "Commit" etc. There's no "Settings" as well. If I just try to commit it will display a warning:

> Use Virtual Studio configuration and overwrite Git configuration

But I can't find that "Visual Studio" configuration anywhere.

Comment: I think your local repo is created that's why you don't see the item in the menu. You are able to commit but you get the warning because you have not set the mandatory name and email in git settings. To do so, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-settings?view=vs-2022#name-and-email

Comment: @Philippe Thanks for your reply. Yes, I've seen that page you linked before, but I can't get to the name/email because there's no "settings" under the "Git" menu.

Comment: If git is in your PATH, maybe it's easier to run the 2 command lines: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-configure-git-username-and-email/#setting-global-git-username-and-email

Comment: @Philippe Thanks again for the link. Yes, git was in my path, with correct name and email. I could not push the code anywhere because the master is not associated to any remote. I created a remote in "remote sources", but on fetch VS displays a fatal error message, even though my user name and password are correct. I removed them from the keychain (Mac) again but VS still gives me the error. At this time I believe it's simply impossible. But thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Github doesn't use authentication using a password (for security purposes) and you have to generate a token in the settings to use it as a password: https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/